# TinyMCE custom tags stop default self closing

Tags: javascript, tags, tinymce, tinymce-4

My TinyMCE custom plugin with custom tag named **MyFirstPlugin** is getting self enclosed like this

```
<myfirstplugin data-set="test" />
```

But I want to save it as

```
<myfirstplugin data-set="test"></myfirstplugin>
```

I have added custom elements and extended valid elements like below

```
extended_valid_elements: "myfirstplugin [*]",
custom_elements: '~myfirstplugin',
```

When I save the textarea with following code in custom plugin js

```
ed.on('SaveContent', function(event){
              event.content = window.myframework.utils.convertCustomTagCase(tomyframeworkMarkup(event.content));
            });
```

then it converts myfirstplugin

```
<myfirstplugin data-set="test"></myfirstplugin>
```

into self enclosing tag.

```
<myfirstplugin data-set="test" />
```

Kindly help me with finding right way to save it without self enclosing tag.

Comment: what happens if you add your custom tag to valid_elements and valid_children?

Comment: Did you find a solution for it? I have the issue the tag doesn't close at all.. both /> as </tag> are removed. Maybe it's related to this problem